# wxPython UltimateListCtrl - deleting last index causes error on IsHighlighted

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython

I am using UltimateListCtrls in my GUI. I added a rightclick menu to the widget and added a delete button to that menu. If the user pushes the button the index where the mouse is, will be deleted.

The problem seems to ne that after this the list tries to recreated the selection/highlighting, but as there is no one row less than before the index gets out of range.

How do i prevent this error? I also tried to delete all items and recreate the list, but also at the "DeleteAllItems" function the error happens.

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "…\lib\site-packages\wx\lib\agw\ultimatelistctrl.py", line 7723, in
>   OnMouse
>       if not self.IsHighlighted(current):   File "…\lib\site-packages\wx\lib\agw\ultimatelistctrl.py", line 6883, in
>   IsHighlighted
>       ld = self.GetLine(line)   File "…\lib\site-packages\wx\lib\agw\ultimatelistctrl.py", line 6438, in
>   GetLine
>       return self._lines[n] IndexError: list index out of range

My List is created like this:

```
    agwStyle = (ULC.ULC_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT | wx.LC_REPORT | wx.LC_VRULES | wx.LC_HRULES | wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL)


    self.list_components = ULC.UltimateListCtrl(component_masterPanel, wx.ID_ANY, agwStyle=agwStyle)
    self.list_components.InsertColumn(0, 'Component', width=90)
    self.list_components.InsertColumn(1, 'Name', width=120)
```

Code which deletes the Index:

```
def OnRightClick(self, event):
    index = event.GetIndex()        
    widget = event.GetEventObject()

    widget.Select(index,True)


    item = widget.GetItem(index, col=0)
    comp_id = item.GetText()

    # Create menu
    popupmenu = wx.Menu()       
    menuItem_1 = popupmenu.Append(-1, 'Delete')           
    wrapper_1 = lambda event: self.OnDeleteComponent(event, index, widget)           
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, wrapper_1, menuItem_1)  

    # Show menu
    self.PopupMenu(popupmenu, self.ScreenToClient(wx.GetMousePosition()))


def OnDeleteComponent(self, event, index=None, widget=None):
    widget.DeleteItem(index)
```

Rolf please see my updated version:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.agw import ultimatelistctrl as ULC

class Mywin(wx.Frame):
    t_col1 = ['PICTURE 1', 'PICTURE 2', 'PICTURE 3', 'PICTURE 4', 'PICTURE 5', 'PICTURE 6', 'PICTURE 7']
    t_col4 = ['1', '1', '3', '5', '5', '1', '2']

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        box2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        title = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, label='Pictures On Frame:')
        box2.Add(title, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.list = ULC.UltimateListCtrl(self, agwStyle = ULC.ULC_REPORT | ULC.ULC_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT)
        colhead = ["", "File", "Ext", "Size", "Rating"]
        colwidth = [30, 300, 45, 45, 45]
        for x in range(0, len(colhead)):
            self.list.InsertColumn(x, colhead[x], width=colwidth[x])
        box2.Add(self.list, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        btnSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        btnC = wx.Button(self, label="Clear")
        btnC.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_clear)
        btnSizer2.Add(btnC, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)
        box2.Add(btnSizer2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(box2)
        self.SetTitle('Picture Frame Selector')
        self.Centre()
        self.Maximize()
        self.CreateList()
        self.Show()

    def CreateList(self):
        rb_list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
        for x in range(0 , len(self.t_col1)):
            self.list.InsertStringItem(x, '')
            cBox = wx.CheckBox(self.list)
            self.list.SetItemWindow(x, 0, cBox)
            self.list.SetStringItem(x, 1, self.t_col1[x])
            self.list.SetStringItem(x, 2, '.jpg')
            dBox = wx.ComboBox(self.list, value=self.t_col4[x], choices=rb_list, style=wx.CB_READONLY)
            self.list.SetItemWindow(x, 4, dBox, expand=True)

            self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_RIGHT_CLICK, self.OnRightClick, self.list)


    def OnRightClick(self, event):
        index = event.GetIndex()        
        widget = event.GetEventObject()                

        popupmenu = wx.Menu()       
        menuItem_1 = popupmenu.Append(-1, 'Delete')           
        wrapper_1 = lambda event: self.OnDeleteComponent(event, index, widget)           
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, wrapper_1, menuItem_1)

        self.PopupMenu(popupmenu, self.ScreenToClient(wx.GetMousePosition()))


    def OnDeleteComponent(self, event, index=None, widget=None):
        widget.DeleteItem(index)


    def on_clear(self, event):
        for x in range(len(self.t_col1) -1 , -1, -1):
            if self.list.GetItemWindow(x, 0).IsChecked():
                self.t_col1.pop(x)
        self.list.DeleteAllItems()
        self.CreateList()
        event.Skip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ex = wx.App()
    Mywin(None, 'Row Delete Issue')
    ex.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This bug seems to have been around for while, where the internal indexing of the ULC seems not to be updated consistently. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52286106/wxpython-ultimatelistctrl-error-after-deleting-row

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i also tried to recreate the list. But at the point i am calling "widget.DeleteAllItems()" the error also occures. As it is not really critical, is there a good way to catch that error and make it kind of invisible?

Comment: Does the error occur within the `DeleteAllItems()` function or when rebuilding the list? I'm not seeing that behaviour.

Comment: The error occures when rebuilding the list, the "isHighlighted" function inside the UltimateListCtrl code is causing the error. The highlighting doesnt seem to update properly to the new List. So the error only occures when the last index or the last item of the list is deleted.

Comment: I can't reproduce that issue on the example given in my link (wxpython 4.1.0 gtk2)

Comment: You are totally right ! Sorry I thought the problem was the UltimateListCtrl but it seems to be the right click menu i used to delete the items. I updated my post with your code and my "problem", maybe you could reproduce the error there. The wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_RIGHT_CLICK doesnt seem to reset the highlighted items properly.

Answer (score 0):

When writing my code, I encountered exactly the same error.

I also call `DeleteAllItems()` from the `wx.Menu()` event, and I get the error "IndexError: list index out of range".

I found a solution.
To eliminate such an error, the function called from the `wx.EVT_MENU` event, in which the deletion occurs, must be called using `wx.CallAfter`.

For your example:

`wx.CallAfter(widget.DeleteItem, index)`